# php shipping charges api

Tags: php

I want to use one api that will calculate shipping charge automatically & return me the price.
please give me solution with one example of api which you will give because i dont know how to use it.

thank you

Comment: Shipping from where to where (continental USA to continental USA? Europe to USA? Anywhere to anywhere?)? Which carrier (USPS? FedEx? UPS?)? Especially your choice of carrier will influence this, as each has a different API.

Comment: Not PHP5 specific, please tag correctly. http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php

Answer (score 1):

You mean, one API that you pass size, weight, sender and recipient address to, that queries all the shipping services that happen to do that route and retrieves a price, taking into consideration all specific requirements, special offers, customs tariffs....? Such a thing doesn't exist, at least not at the moment.

You need to narrow down your requirements (country, shipping services...) to get pointers to existing APIs. They do exist, but each company has its own.

Answer (score 1):

UPS have a shipping API where you can pass in various parameters and get the cost of shipping back from them.  You do, however, need to be a UPS customer to get access to it.